Firebase Callable Function 401 Unauthorized in Flutter App with Require Authentication
I have a Flutter app where users log in with Firebase Authentication (email/password). The app calls a Firebase Callable Function deployed on Google Cloud Functions (Gen 2). The function works with Allow unauthenticated, but fails with Require authentication, returning a 401 Unauthorized.
Setup:
Firebase Function:
const { onCall, HttpsError } = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

if (!admin.apps.length) admin.initializeApp();

exports.simpleTestFunction = onCall(
  { region: "europe-west3" },
  async (request) => {
    if (!request.auth) {
      throw new HttpsError("unauthenticated", "Request is not authenticated.");
    }
    const { uid, token } = request.auth;
    const { message } = request.data;
    return { status: "ok", message: "Function executed successfully." };
  }
);

Flutter Client:
Future<void> _callSimpleTestFunction(String message) async {
  try {
    final functions = FirebaseFunctions.instance;
    final result = await functions.httpsCallable('simpleTestFunction').call({
      "message": message,
    });
    print('Result: ${result.data}');
  } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (error) {
    print('Error Code: ${error.code}');
  }
}

Issue:
I have tried to add Cloud Functions Invoker and Cloud Run Invoker to most service accounts. I also added allAuthenticatedUsers with roles/cloudfunctions.invoker, but I still get 401 Unauthorized with Require authentication.
Question:
Based on the app code and the client Flutter app code:

Should I keep Allow unauthenticated, as the function already verifies the token (request.auth)?
Can I make it work securely with Require authentication?
What’s the best way to secure this function, as it handles sensitive data?

